# Display documents and video in Window phone 7

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, ms-office

I am working on sharepoint integration with windows phone.

As a module of of that i want to display the documents(txt, doc, xls) and video files available on the server on my app.

Also to edit them if possible.

Is there any built tool provided by microsoft for this either in WP7 or Mango.

If not what are the other possibilities for this.

Thanks and Regards

Mohit Leekha

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to play videos using the MediaElement API - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769551(VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to edit documents within your app.

You could open the link to the document on the server in a WebBrowserTask to cause it to be opened by Office.